# Reading Path From Config File

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables

In order to save and read files to a folder in Qt C++ I am reading file pathes from config file line like :

```
[FILEPATHES]
REPORTTEMPLATE=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ReportGenerator\ReportGenerator\Resources\Rapor.xlsx
REPORTOUTPUT=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ReportGenerator\ReportGenerator\Resources\Results.xlsx
```

As you can see,the file path is dependent to user name of computer.

Here I can set an environment variable to store locations of files and read it during run-time to save files there.Also I can get location of executable then direct files to a relative path.

But the locations should be set from a config file.

What I am asking is that, is it possible to use :

```
 [FILEPATHES]
    REPORTTEMPLATE=FILEPATHES\ReportsFolder 
    REPORTOUTPUT=FILEPATHES\ReportsFolder
```

where FILEPATHES is an environment variable name.If so how can I use it in Qt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the paths in the config file relative to the environment variable, so you would have:

```
[FILEPATHES]
REPORTTEMPLATE=ReportsFolder 
REPORTOUTPUT=ReportsFolder
```

...and then prepend the result of `std::getenv("FILEPATHES")` to each path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions from the [`<QtGlobal>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html) include:

- [`qgetenv()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv) to get an environment variable
- [`qputenv()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qputenv) to set an environment variable
- [`qunsetenv()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qunsetenv) to unset an environment variable